# How is the Stack Exchange API documentation generated?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange-2.0, api

I was just going through the pile of SE websites and just found [Stack Exchange API](http://api.stackexchange.com/docs?tab=category#docs). The documentation for each  REST endpoint or URL is given in detail. Also, the API methods are listed and a separate page is given to describe each REST endpoint.

1. **API Methods:**

   [image]
2. **Individual Method Description:**

   [image]

Stack Exchange is built using C#, ASP.NET MVC evident from [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10370/205459)., and many other technologies. What language is the Stack Exchange API written in?

If it is written in C#, then what tools are used for documentation? How is the documentation created?Are they using only XML comments or some library?

Comment: They do have a mild case of NIH, so it's probably a custom solution. It works for them, they usually create something much better than what is already out there.

Comment: @CodyGray "they usually create something much better than what is already out there", no doubt about that. I am curious how such documentation is built. It's awesome..

Comment: Speaking of the API, I wish that it wasn't only read only off of the site, a true SE App where you could post questions and answers would be amazing.

Comment: Wouldn't this mess with some ad agreement SE has? By doing that you allow some API client to bypass the ads and create an ad-free SO or worse, a SO app that advertises competitors of the SO advertisers... I'm sure the answer is along those lines...

Comment: Any answer on this?

Comment: @retailcoder  not sure what you mean. You mean the API itself? Bypassing SO's ads is easy by using the data dump, you are explicitly allowed to set up web sites with SO's content in direct competition.

Comment: "Stack Overflow is built using C#," should be "Stack **Exchange** is built using C#,"

Comment: @hjpotter92 Yeah ...amended my question for this correction...

Comment: @Pekka웃 that was for TheProgramm3r's comment regarding *posting* content, not just consuming it. But yeah would be nice.

Comment: Maybe they use C#'s XML comments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Stack Exchange API is a .NET MVC4 app written in C# 4 (technically 5 now, but it isn't using any `async/await` stuff).

The index page is just a view, maintained more or less by hand.

For methods there's nothing magic there, it's just a collection of views with a common master.  A similar approach is taken for types.

Here's (most of) the view for `/answers`

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Documentation/Method.cshtml";
}

@section MethodName { /answers }

@section Discussion
{
<p>Returns all the undeleted answers in the system.</p>

<p>The sorts accepted by this method operate on the follow fields of the <a href="/docs/types/answer">answer object</a>:
    <ul>
        <li><strong>activity</strong> &ndash; <code>last_activity_date</code></li>
        <li><strong>creation</strong> &ndash; <code>creation_date</code></li>
        <li><strong>votes</strong> &ndash; <code>score</code></li>
    </ul>

    @(DocsTypeDescriber.DefaultSort<AnswerSort>())<br>
    <br>

    It is possible to <a href="/docs/min-max">create moderately complex queries</a> using <code>sort</code>, <code>min</code>, <code>max</code>, <code>fromdate</code>, and <code>todate</code>.
</p>
}

@section Type
{
    <p>This method returns a list of <a href="/docs/types/answer">answers</a>.</p>
}

@section ConsoleParameters
{
    @{
        var param = ApiParameters.DescribeWithSort<AnswerSort>();
        var filterName = ApiFilter.Default.EncodeFilter();
        var filter = ApiFilter.Default.Describe("2.1");
        var dependentTypes = StackOverflow.Api.V2.Helpers.FilterableAttribute.GetDependentFilterableTypes(typeof(Answer)).Keys.Union(new[] { typeof(ApiResult<>) }).Select(s => s.GetApiName()).ToList();
    }
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var parameters = @param.ToJSON();
        var method = "/2.1/answers";
        var filterName = "@filterName";
        var filter = @filter.ToJSON();
        var dependentTypes = @dependentTypes.ToJSON();
    </script>
}
```

Our API is very regular, so all the documentation views look very similar.

This system is "new" (I guess years old now) to v2.0.  In v1.0 we did try some automatic documentation generation using in source comments but it turned into a maintenance nightmare, and was kind of difficult to make work with more interesting methods.